# Inner class that contains instance of abstract class: getting "Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object"

Tags: android, serialization

i know that there are similar topics to mine but non of them helps me to deal with my situation.

I have a class which contains an inner serialized non-static class in it.
The crash is happening when I'm pressing on the device "home" key(and app is going to the background)

This is my code

```
public class pageParam implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7793437011565026799L;

    public OnCloseListener onCloseListener;
    public long userId;
    public boolean hasName;
    public int age;

    public pageParam(OnCloseListener onCloseListener, long userId,
            boolean userId, int age) {
        this.onCloseListener = onCloseListener;
        this.userId = userId;
        this.hasName = hasName;
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

and

```
public abstract class OnCloseListener implements Serializable {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = -143252315312L;

    public abstract void onCloseListener();
}
```

please notice that OnCloseListener is abstract and I have the possibility to add serialVersionUID in the implementation of OnCloseListener(with or without doing it, it fails)

EDIT:

this is the implementation of OnCloseListener():

```
OnCloseListener OnCloseListener = new OnCloseListener() {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8848214522109319925L;

    @Override
    public void OnCloseListener() {
        ......
 }
}
```

as you can see, it has also serial key.

EDIT 2:

Even after I change OnCloseListener to be regular class (not abstract) I still got this exception error.

public class OnCloseListener implements Serializable {

```
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2718040340149001112L;

    public void OnClose() {
        ......
   } 
}
```

Maybe it got to do with the code inside OnClose()? Im doing there some operations on the upper class.

Comment: can you post the concrete implementation of onCloseListener you are using ? (which i think (not sure) must also implement Serializable explicitely (don't remember why, though))

Comment: I think it would do to remove `abstract` from the declaration of `OnCloseListener`; what is it supposed to do? I don't think abstract objects can successfully be serialized.